# Pandas, How to select a set amount of dataframe columns with the .loc funtion

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple rows and columns. I have one gender col. that is occupied by values between 0 - 2. I have another col. called ignore with values either true or false.

I want to select only 50% of the gender col. with values of 2, and those should change their corresponding ignore col. value to True.

Now I have the `.loc` function to find all genders with values of 2, and they then change their ignore values to True. But how could I improve the `.loc` function to change only 50% of the #2 gender values, not all of the #2s?

Should I split the df with a `.group_by`, or something else?

```
df.loc[(df['gender'] == 2), 'ignore'] = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 100
d = pd.DataFrame({'gender': np.random.choice(range(3), N),
                  'ignore': np.random.choice([True, False], N)})

d.query('gender == 2').sample(frac = 0.5).assign(ignore = True)
```